# cross_val_score in Ridge/Lasso regression

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am running a Ridge regression in a Jupyter notebook, which I attach here.

```
ridge = Ridge(alpha=optimal_ridge.alpha_)

ridge_scores = cross_val_score(ridge, Xs, y, cv=10)

print(ridge_scores)
print(np.mean(ridge_scores))`
```

When applying the funcion cross_val_score to my estimator, what metric does it give me? I obtain 10 values lower than 1 (that come from the cross validation), which are:

```
[0.90397003 0.88391849 0.77181566 0.85037008 0.85705655 0.88257961
 0.9114154  0.91447498 0.93543431 0.93167352]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn-model-selection-cross-val-score), it uses "the estimator’s default scorer (if available)". In your case, the estimator is Ridge and its `score` function returns "the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction" as stated in [its docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.score).

Also, you can define your own scoring function and pass it to `cross_val_score` as a parameter ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)):

```
def your_scorer(estimator, X, y):
    ...

cross_val_score(ridge, Xs, y, cv=10, scoring=your_scorer)
```